# Getting the following error on points function

Tags: c++, abstract-class

Hi I am getting the following error when i am trying to compile my code.
 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.' when i call

Points.addPoints();
Thanks for any help.

```
#ifndef _POINTS_H
#define _POINTS_H
//points.h 

#include <sstream>

using namespace std;


class Points{

int pointsADD;
int pointsRemove;
int newPoints;

public :


    Points(int points){this->pointsADD=points;this->pointsRemove=pointsRemove;this->newPoints=newPoints;}



void addPoints(int newPointsADD){
        newPoints=pointsADD+newPointsADD++;
    }

void removePoints(int newPointsRemove){
    newPoints=pointsRemove+newPointsRemove--;

}

int getPoints(){
    return newPoints;
}

};

#endif
```

Comment: Need to see the code you're getting the error in :)

Comment: This is either a very ghc-esque error or you are not showing the error's line. Could you please indicate the line with the error?

Comment: `void cowCollision(){
 if (cowModel.testcollison(g_Camera.getPositionX(), g_Camera.getPositionY(),0,45)){
 Points.addPoints();//this is where i get the  error

  bench.visible=false;
 


    }
}`

Comment: your missing a ; above the scope of the function cowCollision().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an instance of the class to add anything. Read a good C++ introduction, and fix for now:

```
Points p(42);
p.addPoints(23);
```

Comment: dur, how'd i miss that :)) i need some coffee sheesh

Comment: Thanks that fixed the issue although I already did something similar before I just removed it for some reason.